# Yii how to use model update even if the record is new

Tags: php, mysql, performance, yii

I have a system which is very important to be as close to realtime as possible.
For this reason when i'm fetching data from external source i want to use $model->update instead of executing 2 queries :

```
$model->find()
if(new)
    $model->save
else
    $model->update
```

This is too time consuming...can i use $model->update and if the record is new it will simply create it?

I looked at the code for update, but i'm not sure how to override it.

```
public function update($attributes=null)
{
    if($this->getIsNewRecord())
        throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','The active record cannot be updated because it is new.'));
    if($this->beforeSave())
    {
        Yii::trace(get_class($this).'.update()','system.db.ar.CActiveRecord');
        if($this->_pk===null)
            $this->_pk=$this->getPrimaryKey();
        $this->updateByPk($this->getOldPrimaryKey(),$this->getAttributes($attributes));
        $this->_pk=$this->getPrimaryKey();
        $this->afterSave();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Too time consuming? Why? Where exactly is the time being consumed?

Comment: It's not possible to do any of the CRUD statements 'combined' or without the need to have the other one. You cannot say to the database `Make a new record in the table by updating a not existing one`. You can't mix up `INSERT INTO <table>` with `UPDATE <table> WHERE`. You're bound by the limitations of regular database query languages. BUT: as stated in the answer below `http://stackoverflow.com/a/16336521/431967` you can just do $model->save().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$model->save
```

works the same way you want. if the model is new it will insert and if model exist it will update.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#updating-record

> As we can see, we use the same save() method to perform insertion and
>   updating operations. If an AR instance is created using the new
>   operator, calling save() would insert a new row into the database
>   table; if the AR instance is the result of some find or findAll method
>   call, calling save() would update the existing row in the table.

Comment: unfortunately model->save will save each record and wont update since i'm looping and creating a new model each time....but based on the answers here i understand this is what i have to do.

Comment: If you are sure that it is an existing model you can set isNewRecord to false. Then save() will performe an update.
Or use the ActiveRecord::update() method. But you will have no validation then.

Comment: @DannyValariola it's inserting each time since you don't have a unique key in your database or else how would it know that the model exists.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do anything

$model->isNewRecord will check the record is new or not before execute the query.

so $model->save will create the new record if the $model->isNewRecord returns "true",

where as if it returns "false" $model->save will update the record with respect to primary key .